# how to avoid new socket connection on browser reload?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

how to avoid new socket connection on page refresh? I have a game which starts on two socket connections in a room but during the middle of the game i refresh the page and the game progress is lost and a new game starts if there is a new opponent waiting.I want this to be avoided , any idea? Plese help , i am really stuck into this

server.js

```
  function onClientdisconnect() {
   console.log('player disconnected with id ' + this.id);
   //send message to every connected client except the sender
   this.broadcast.to(this.room_id).emit('remove_player', {id: this.id});}

  io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
  console.log('user connected ' + socket.id);
  socket.on('disconnect', onClientdisconnect);
```

client.js

```
   var socket =io();
    // socket connection
socket.on('connect',function(){

  socket.emit('new_player_GK',{
      id:socket.id 
  });
  console.log('connected');
});
```

Comment: Can you share a snippet of your code ?

Comment: i have edited it. Not written the whole game logic but written the concerned parts

Answer (score 3):

You can't, the websocket connection is closed automatically when the page is closed (refreshed).

You would have to implement your own session logic, maybe store cookie/localStorage data on the client side and restore the (previous) client data on page load.

If your game data is stored on the server, you would have to implement some sort of authentication so you know that ***game data X*** is from ***user Y***, so when ***user Y*** (identified based on cookies) loads the page again the server returns his previous ***data X***.

If you need a more specific example you would first have to explain what data you want to be persisted between page loads, keeping in mind that persisting the websocket connection is not possible. I would recommend instead making your game work more like a [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) so you entirely eliminate the need to refresh (this still won't maintain progress if user intentionally refreshes the page or closes the tab).

Comment: i am using passport.socketio ,and passportjs for authentication, how to proceed further?

Comment: Because you say that the "game progress" is lost, you would have to implement methods to "save" the game progress and to "load" the game progress. You can save it either on the client (not that secure) or on the server. I recommend saving the progress on a persistent storage medium on the server (database or text file).

Comment: how to save the game progress? I am sorry i am unable to do this

Comment: how to save the game progress? I am sorry i am unable to do this. it's a quiz game which is a  1v1 game, played between only two opponents and page data changes after every 10secs as new questions are generated, so supoose i refresh at the moment when i was being served the 3rd question, i want that after i refresh i am being served what i would have been served pre-refresh

Comment: i have commented what page data i want to persist , please provide me some suggestions on how to achieve it

Comment: @roh_dev So, assuming your questions have an unique ID and that you also have the current question number (eg: 2/5), the game state on the server is given by those two things (questionID, currentQuestionIndex). You have to save those on the server, so when you get a new random question you increase the `currentQuestionIndex` and save the` questionID` of the random question. When the client connects you send him the question and current progress (2nd question out of 5). You might also want to save scores/answers.